# Scaling monotonically increasing features between 0 and 1

Tags: lstm, rnn, feature-engineering, feature-scaling

To keep the test set blind to the neural network algorithm it is generally better to build a scaler based on the training set and then scale the test set on this scaler.

I am building an LSTM for predicting a somewhat monotonically increasing price chart. I am not shuffling the data before splitting into training and testing since the sequence is important.

This will mean that the test set can have values higher than 1 (say 1.2, 1.01 etc...)

Would this be a problem to the neural network? Is it important that every input to the neural network be less than zero if that is what it was trained with?

Comment: What are you scaling? Your input? Your target? Both? What does your data look like? What are the dimensions of your input/output?

Comment: Scaling both input and target. As I said in the title my data looks somewhat monotonically increasing. Why does the dimensions matter? All I am questioning is if the well-adopted method of making a scaler based on the training data and then scale the testing holds for a non shuffled dataset for `lstm`. just because all the testing data would be all  > 1 due to this monotonically increasing pattern.

Comment: It never hurts that this type of information. At first glance, I am confused about why you are scaling your target? Shouldn't be necessary. And are your features also increasing? In theory, having features or targets above one isn't a bad thing, so you should be fine. But again, do try and see what kind of results you get.

Comment: this link shows conflicting arguments for and against scaling target so I went with the safest bet. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re. Yes features are increasing.